# Kapparos on money - How much?

Tags: minhag, money, shiurim-measurements, aseres-yemei-teshuva, kaparot

If one does the Minhag of [Kapparos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kapparot) on money, how much money should be used for each person? (Sources.)

Answer (score 9):

[Nitei Gavriel Yom Kippur 10:17](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46445&st=&pgnum=78) says that it should be done with money that equals the value of a chicken.

Comment: http://www.mypetchicken.com/about-chickens/frequently-asked-questions.aspx#Cost

Comment: http://wiki.answers.com/Q/How_much_does_a_chicken_cost

Comment: My Rov said in shiur tonight it should be a multiple of 18 (currency units or maybe coins).

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok 18?? Isn't that the gematria of חטא??

Comment: @DoubleAA and chai!!

Comment: Anyone know the current market value of a chicken (if updated since 2012)? And should it be the value of an adult chicken, or a chick?