# Kaparot on Erev Yom Kipur

Tags: kaparot

What's the reason of kaparot?
Why with a chicken?
Why do we shecht it?
And why on Erev Yom Kipur (can I do it every other time of the year)?
Is it halacha or a minhag?
Thanks

Comment: The Mishna Berurah says it represents the same notion as a *korban*, you should imagine that the chicken etc. has gone in your place.

Comment: "What is the origin of the minhag of kapparot?"
 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/117659/what-is-the-origin-of-the-minhag-of-kapparot/117662#117662

Answer (score 0):

There is a comprehensive article which addresses each of your questions [here](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/989585/jewish/Kaparot.htm):

> The custom of performing kaparot with a chicken dates back to late
> Talmudic times. The earliest extant record specifically discussing the
> use of a chicken is a responsum from Rav Sheshna Gaon who lived in the
> early Geonic (post-Talmudic) period (approx. 660 C.E.). Rav Sheshna
> takes it for granted that his reader knows about the custom, a clear
> indication that it was widespread at the time. Some commentaries point
> to passages in the Talmud itself that allude to this custom.
>
> Several reasons have been suggested for the choice of a chicken to
> perform the kaparot rite:
>
> 1. In Aramaic, a rooster is known as a gever. In Hebrew, a gever is a man. Thus we take a gever to atone for a gever.
> 2. A chicken is a commonly found fowl and relatively inexpensive.
> 3. It is not a species that was eligible to be offered as a sacrifice in the Holy Temple. This precludes the possibility that someone might
>    erroneously conclude that the kaparot is an offering.
>
> ...We ask of G‑d that if we were destined to be the recipients of harsh
> decrees in the new year, may they be transferred to this chicken in
> the merit of this mitzvah of charity.
>
> It is important to keep in mind that the chicken is not an offering.
> Neither does performance of the ceremony alone atone for one’s sins.
> However, the ceremony does shake one up a little.

Comment: This answer was already brought here - https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/117662/22152